# parse_expr() in sympy not working no matter the arguments I include

Tags: python, parsing, sympy

I'm trying to make a program that takes user input to answer the correct mathematical expression using a variable 's' but every time I use parse_expr and then try to do mathematical operations on the user-inputted expression to determine equality, I get an error saying "can only concatenate str (not int) onto str", which lets me know that the parse_expr function did not do what it was supposed to do. I have tried including the relevant arguments but to no avail. What am I missing? (This is test code and not exactly what I'm including in my program but it still doesn't work)

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
s = sp.symbols('s')
expression = '25*s + 40 + 25*s'
parse_expr(expression, local_dict={'s': s})
expression += 10
print(expression)
```

Comment: You need to catch the result of `parse_expr`, e.g. `expression = parse_expr(expression, local_dict={'s': s})`

Comment: oh wow... well I am incredibly thankful for the help, no matter how obvious it may have seemed to you